# The ParseInLocation method produces incorrect results for certain years

Tags: go, time, timezone, timezone-offset

```
func main() {
    timeStr := "1974-05-10 10:30:00"
    timeStr2 := "1975-11-10 10:30:00"

    timeZone := "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh"

    location, err := time.LoadLocation(timeZone)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Load Location error :", err)
        return
    }

    parsedTime1, err := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02 15:04:05", timeStr, location)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Format error:", err)
        return
    }

    parsedTime2, err2 := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02 15:04:05", timeStr2, location)
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Format error:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("parsed time 1:", parsedTime1)
    fmt.Println("parsed time 2:", parsedTime2)

}
```

Playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/RV7hXchRcNx

Output:

```
parsed time 1: 1974-05-10 10:30:00 +0800 +08
parsed time 2: 1975-11-10 10:30:00 +0700 +07
```

Output in Goand: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxDPZ.png)

The time zone is correct for executions after the year 1975.

You can view the screenshot above.

Answer (score 5):

Ho Chi Minh city is in South Vietnam. Quoting from [Wikipedia: Time in Vietnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Vietnam):

> ### History
>
> - ...
> - South Vietnam time zone was changed to UTC+08:00 from 23:00, 31 December 1959, passing 60 minutes.
> - ...
> - Following the Fall of Saigon in April–May 1975, reunified Vietnam then observes UTC+07:00 with Saigon (and other southern parts) delaying 60 minutes on 13 June 1975.

So between 31 December, 1959 and May 1975 there was +08:00 offset in South Vietnam, and since 13 June, 1975 there is +07:00. Your output is correct, it takes historical changes into account.